# How to loop through a total string and diplay one character at a time C++

Tags: c++

I am trying to create a program that prompts user to enter a string to create a very simple animation. My code works properly, however, when I am trying to display the string I cannot quite get it to work (second function) Please Help!

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <string>
 #include <cmath>

using namespace std;


void getAnimation(string& animation);
void displayAnimation(string& animation);

int main()
{
  string animation;

  getAnimation(animation);

  displayAnimation(animation);

  return 0;
}


//Ask user to enter a single frame 
//returned as string
//Input Parameters: Numeber of Frames, Number of Lines, and Animation 
//Returns: The animation (string)
void getAnimation(string& animation)
{
  int counter, lines, i, numLines, frameNum;

  cout << "How many frames of animation would you like?" << endl;
  cin >> numLines;

  // numbers to help with for - loop
  counter = 0;
  frameNum = 1;

  //for - loop to get information
  for (counter = 0; counter < numLines; counter++)
  {
    cout << "How many lines do you want in this frame?" << endl;
    cin >> lines;

    for (i = 0; i < lines; ++i)
    {
      cout << "Give me line of frame #" << frameNum++ << endl;
      cin >> animation;
      //getline(cin, animation);
      //cin.ignore();
    }
  }
}

//Will gather the string received in main and gather it here to display
//Returned full animation
//Input Parameters: None
//Output Parameters: Animation
void displayAnimation(string& animation)
{
  cout << "Here is your super-sweet animation!\n";

  // to print out entire animation

  //for (auto c : animation)
    //cout << animation << endl;
  //for (int i = 0; i < animation.length(); i++);
}
```

Comment: What is exact problem being faced?

Comment: The program only outputs the last characters that I typed in rather than the entire string.

Comment: The last value placed in `animation` within `getAnimation` is the one that returns to `main()`, where you then pass it (and **only** it) to `displayAnimation`. If that isn't your intent, change the code.

Answer (score 1):

`animation` is a `string` not an array or so therefore `for (auto c : animation)` wont work. To get a single character simply do `animation.at(i)` where `i` is the index of the character you want.

You could also use a `stringstream`.

```
char c;
std::istringstream iss(animation)

while (iss.get(c))
{
  // Do animation here
}
```

And dont forget to include `sstream`.

---

Also there is another problem in your code. You're expecting `animation` to hold severale lines of input, right? Since `aninamtion` is a `std::string` not an array or a `vector` as I mentioned it before you're overiding its value the hole time by using `cin >> animation`. You should use a `std::vector<string>` for your approach.

So declare animation like so `std::vector<string> animation` and in `getAnimation` you would then need to do something like that:

```
for (i = 0; i < lines; ++i)
{ 
   cout << "Give me line of frame #" << frameNum++ << endl;
   string tmp;
   cin >> tmp;
   animation.push_back(tmp);
}
```

In `displayAnimation` you should then first loop over the `vector` and then over the `strings` it stores to get the single characters.

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < animation.size(); ++i)
{
  istringstream iss(animation.at(i));
  char c;
  while (iss.get(c))
  {
    cout << c;
  }
}
```

You also need to change the function declaration to `void getAnimation(vector<string>& animation)` and `void displayAnimation(vector& animation)